# What is the name of this rule? $ c\lor (a \land \lnot c)= c \lor a $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> What is the name of this rule?
> $$ c\lor (a \land \lnot c)= c \lor a $$

I know if $c$ is true then the right side does not matter. If $c$ is false, then it all depends on $a$. But what is the rule called?

Comment: I don't know if this identity has a *name*, but you can readily derive it using a Distributive Property.

Comment: i have never seen this specific identity named before. but you can certainly derive from known identities.

Comment: The RHS is the CNF of the LHS.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: the RHS is **a** CNF of the LHS. The LHS is already in conjunctive normal form: CNFs aren't unique.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry, I don't get it. The LHS is a disjunction of conjunctions, not a conjunction of disjunctions. And (with a proper ordering of terms) the full cnf/full dnf is unique.

Comment: In the derivation you'd use the distributive law to yield (c v a)^(c v ~c) and an identity law to yield c v a. That is, the semantic reasoning for the second step is that the truth of the conjunction here depends only on c v a since c v ~c is always true, i.e. regardless what the value of c is. But I'm also unaware of the name of the identity you have expressed.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: apologies. I misread your rule. Nonetheless, I am right that CNFs aren't unique, so you should say $\mathbf{a}$ CNF not $\mathbf{the}$ CNF.

Comment: This is funny! “You can have soup, or you can have salad without soup. Or you can have both.”

Answer (score 0):

Together with its dual form $c \land (a \lor \neg c)$, I have long referred to this equivalence as **Reduction**: the way I talk about it, the $c$ term ‘reduces’ the $a \land \neg c$ term to just $a$.

While Reduction can be derived from other principles, when doing boolean algebra I find it to be super useful to be able to do this in 1 step: it is syntactically easy to remember and apply, it is semantically fairly intuitive (certainly the dual version is), and it comes up many, many times when doing boolean algebra. So, I think it definitively deserves its own name and should be a fixture in any list of boolean algebra equivalences.

In fact, during the many years I have used it I thought for sure I saw this equivalence named as Reduction somewhere, but doing a quick search now I find that nothing comes up other than myself using it in answer to other MSE questions. Hey, if I turn out to be the first to name it I’ll gladly take the credit, LOL

EDIT: I wonder if I adopted the usage of ‘reduction’ as it is used in the Davis-Putnam algorithm. There, you ‘reduce’ a clause (or clause set) with regard to a unit literal by taking out any complement of that literal from the clause (or clause set). E.g. the clause $\{ a, \neg c \}$ (which of course can be seen to represent $a \lor \neg c $) would reduce to just $\{ a \}$ with regard to $c$.

Comment: @ryang Tough.  I can understand that people want to close the question since some variation of it has been asked a zillion times before.  But I also hate the practice of just pointing to one of those earlier times and act as if the answers provided there cover the gambit of ideas, arguments, and insights on this issue. And I agree, the answers given for the specific ‘duplicate’ they list here certainly are nowhere close to such a full discussion.  I wish there was some way to point to a whole list of older questions and answers … but in the absence of that, sure, I’ll vote to reopen.